# HTML reports from SQL Server stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, report

I need to know the shortest path to create HTML reports directly from SQL Server stored procedures. I would prefer not to involve too many technologies and layers between the two.

I have looked into web applications and SSRS (SQL Server Reporting Services), but wanted to know if there are other quicker alternatives out there that I am not aware of. The Idea is to quickly get an html table report from the database.

Two more features that will be great to have are:

- To be able to schedule the reports to run (say, weekly).
- And to email the URL of the report to the email addresses listed in a column of the report.

Any ideas on how can this be achieved?

Thanks.

Comment: SSRS - quick, easy, does what you need out of the box. No reason to look further.

Comment: Yes, had you left it at creation of html reports to a web page there might have been alternatives. But as as soon as you added scheduled and emailed reports, then SSRS is a no-brainer.

Comment: SSRS is good, but you have to design reports first. Plus, we have to purchase Enterprise edition of SQL server for the data driven email subscription we need. Probably this is what we will end up doing, but I thought I check around for any alternatives before we jump in for SSRS.

Comment: You can emulate a lot of what Data Driven subscriptions can do. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Reporting+Services+(SSRS)/163119/ https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4249/simulate-reporting-services-data-driven-subscriptions-on-unsupported-editions/ . OTOH, if all you want is an HTML table, couldn't you just add HTML tags around each column and row of your query to format it?

Comment: @Hannover Thanks for the link! I didn't know we could call SSRS from sprocs. Worth giving a try. I certainly can add HTML tags around columns, but how do I present the HTML then? ASP.Net or SSRS can take care of setting up the website, but I was not planning for ASP.Net or SSRS for the reasons I have mentioned in the original post. Thanks for the link any way!